# macOS High Sierra Terminal keystroke to switch windows

Tags: macos, terminal, keystroke

I keep nine Terminal windows open at all times. On previous versions, CMD 1 brought me to the first window, CMD 9 to the ninth, etc. But last night I upgraded a MacBook Pro to High Sierra, and now, to switch to Terminal Window K (where K=1, 2, ..., 9) it has to be OPT CMD K. This is awkward for typing; is there a way to make it respond to simply CMD K, as before?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Terminal -> Preferences -> General tab. Near the bottom, it says "escape sequences". un-check "use CMD-1 through CMD-9 to switch tabs." 
Then I can use those sequences to switch windows.